# .htaccess redirects to /index.php instead of preserving the full URI

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I need my .htaccess file to redirect the requests like this:

- OK: "example.com" -> "https://www.example.com/"
- OK: "http://example.com/" -> "https://www.example.com/"
- OK: "http://www.example.com/" -> "https://www.example.com/"
- NOT OK: "example.com/p/product-title" -> "https://www.example.com/p/product-title" (how it should be) / "https://www.example.com/index.php" (how it currently is)
- NOT OK: "http://example.com/p/product-title" -> "https://www.example.com/p/product-title" (how it should be) / "https://www.example.com/index.php" (how it currently is)
- NOT OK: "http://www.example.com/p/product-title" -> "https://www.example.com/p/product-title" (how it should be) / "https://www.example.com/index.php" (how it currently is)

This is my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
    SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto "https" HTTPS=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
 
</IfModule>

<Files .env>
    order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

Comment: You are doing this too late, such a general redirect should always be pretty much the _first_ thing you do.